# Why is AngularJS json data nested?

Tags: angularjs, json, object, nested

I have a service returning this simple json:

```
{
   "successYN": true,
   "msg": "Success!",
   "errors": null
}
```

I have this controller:

```
app.controller('formController', function ($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
var frmVM = this
frmVM.formData = {}

frmVM.frmSubmit = function () {
    console.log('form was submitted with: ' + frmVM.formData.name + ' ' + frmVM.formData.superheroAlias)

    // post the data to the back end
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/contact-post',
            data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(frmVM.formData),  // pass in data as strings
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        })
        .then(function (data) {

            console.log(data);

            var innerData = data.data;

            console.log(innerData)
            console.log(innerData.errors)
            console.log(innerData.successYN)

            if (!innerData.successYN) {
                console.log("Not successful!")
                // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
                frmVM.errorName = innerData.errors.name;
                frmVM.errorSuperhero = innerData.errors.superheroAlias;
            } else {
                // if successful, bind success message to message
                frmVM.message = innerData.msg;
            }
        });
    };
})
```

I have `controller as` syntax in my form and everything works fine. However, the
data object I am seeing in looks like this:

[image]

Therefore, the data has to be accessed like this:

```
 var innerData = data.data;
```

Before I can access the data:

```
 console.log(innerData.successYN)
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and/or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong. It's the response from the http request builder in AngularJS. It added some response headers, information about the request and the `data` wich is retrieved from the server. It stored the data in a `data` object where you can access the JSON object keys from your json file

Comment: thanks, you should put this as an answer as it best explains what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In argument "data" is basically response object which contains response headers as well as body of the response.
ForExample:
If you need the argument response then to get response data you will have to call

`var data = response.data`

and If you want to get header from response you will have to do following:

```
var authorization = response.headers('Authorization');
```

In .then function you will have to pass 2 handlers 1 for success response(200 OK) and 2nd for failure response(400 Bad Request)

So

```
.then(function(response) {
// here you extract data from response. like response.data
}, function(errorResponse) {
// handle error here like errorResponse.status
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But I have seen code doing stuff like this `.success(function(data) {    if (!data.success) {`.  Why am I having to do `data.data.success`?

Comment: Brother Please see update. You have to do it like this. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Usage of .success is discouraged please see following link
http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-%24https-success/

Comment: thanks, I think the comment from @C0dekid above explains it best. I am using Nancy at the back end and it is creating a response object with headers etc and the data is embedded lower into that object. The example I am following uses PHP `echo json_encode($data);` which I think just returns a string.

Comment: But, I changed `.then(function (data) {`  to `.then(function (response) {` and it makes sense now and I can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

The `$http` will return the data in the below format only because that is how it is defined.

The response from the server is an object with these properties:

> 1) .config the object used to generate the request.
>
> 2) .data a string, or an object, carrying the response from the
>   server.
>
> 3) .headers a function to use to get header information.
>
> 4) .status a number defining the HTTP status.
>
> 5) .statusText a string defining the HTTP status.